# Turn Byte() into a Null Value

Tags: vb.net, workflow-foundation-4

I am utilizing Visual Basic within a Windows Workflow Foundation Environment. Workflow is very limited with it's drag-and-drop interface so no outside coding can be done.

I am trying to turn a Byte() containing a PDF document into a null value so it can be saved into the database. Trying to use `DbNull.Value` provides an error stating it can't be converted to a '1-dimensional array of byte'. Putting in an empty byte just keeps the image exactly how it is. How can I get this to keep as null?

Comment: @braX My bad, it's VB.NET through Windows Workflow Foundation. Added the wrong tag, fixed it now.

Comment: Have you tried assigning an empty array to the variable or property to be saved? An empty array literal is `{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property was coming in as Null to the API I am posting to but the API can't handle null values. Not an issue with the code but the API just can't handle null values. Will mark as complete in a few days once StackOverflow lets me.